# CakePhp restriction folder upload

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm looking for a way to block access to the webroot / upload directory.

I tried with an htaccess but the problem is that on the backoffice side I can no longer recover the images and documents

[width htaccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXamC.png)

```
<Location "upload">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Location>
```

Do you know a solution to have access to BO side but not by typing the complete url of the directory?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for. -     https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/protected-directory-for-extern-access/1323

Answer (score 0):

You should move your upload directory out from webroot as you cannot display files that are outside the webroot via a direct URL.

Here is more info about this:

[CakePHP - Saving and serving files outside of webroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720652/cakephp-saving-and-serving-files-outside-of-webroot)

Comment: hello, thanks but I have to create a symbolic link now? My url now D:\laragon\www\test\app\upload/5/discount.png not work :(

Comment: any idea ? I am stuck

Comment: No symbolic links, just move the upload directory D:\laragon\upload. This way the webserver cannot access it. Obviously you need to change your code accordingly "D:\laragon\www\test\app\upload/" -> D:\laragon\upload (assuming D:\laragon\www is your webroot)